# Closed form for system of recurrence

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations, matrix-equations

I stumbled across the system of recurrence $$a_m(k)=m \, a_m(k-1) + (m-1) \, a_{m-1}(k-1)$$ where $m=1,...,k+1$ and $a_{k+1}(k-1)=0$. This means $a_{k+1}(k)=k\,a_{k}(k-1)=k! \, a_1(0)$. For the other components we have the matrix recurrence form
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} a_1(k) \\ a_2(k) \\ a_3(k) \\ \vdots \\ a_{k-1}(k) \\ a_k(k) \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 &  \dots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 &  \dots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & k-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & k-1 & k \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_1(k-1) \\ a_2(k-1) \\ a_3(k-1) \\ \vdots \\ a_{k-1}(k-1) \\ a_k(k-1) \end{pmatrix} \\
&=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 &  \dots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 &  \dots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & k-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & k-1 & k \end{pmatrix}^k \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where $a_1(0)=1$. Is it possible to find closed form?